# Unmerge request.args parameters in Python Flask server

Tags: python, flask, url, query-string

I have a Python Flask server that gets simple HTTP requests.

For my own reasons, I want to prevent Flask automatically merge similar parameters by their names.

For example, if I send a HTTP request with `/?name=a&name=b`, the Flask automatically convert it in the `flask.request.args` to: `/?name=a,b`.

I tried parsing the URL with `urllib.parse` but it didn't work.

This is the code if it's relevant.

```py
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

query_string = request.query_string.decode()
parameters = parse_qs(query_string)
if "name" in parameters:
    name_values = parameters["name"]
    name_list = []
    for name in name_values:
        name_list.extend(name.split(","))
    # do something with the list of name values
```

How can I do this?

Comment: So do you want `['a, b']` or `['a', 'b']`?!

Answer (score 0):

> `Flask` automatically convert it in the `flask.request.args` to: `/?name=a,b`.

No, not really. [`flask.request.args`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.Request.args) is a [`MultiDict`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict) which contains the parsed values; its structure and contents is in no way "`/?name=a,b`". It has methods to get values of keys which occur multiple times:

```
names = request.args.getlist('name')  # ['a', 'b']
```

Comment: I tried it.
It gave me this: `['a,b']`.

Comment: If the request URL actually contained `/?name=a&name=b`, that *should* not be the case…!?

Comment: Yeah it shouldn't be the case because I entered 2 parameters and got a list with one element

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Flask automatically merges parameters with the same name. However, I understand that you want to parse server-side parameters that have been pre-merged.

I would suggest you the following way to parse `/?name=a,b`.

```py
names = request.args.get('name', [], type=lambda x: x.split(','))
```

Comment: Yeah I actually tried something like this.
The problem is when I enter `/?name=a,b`, I'll get `['a', 'b']` in `names`, instead of `['a,b']`.

Comment: What do you expect as a result?

Comment: If I enter `/?name=a,b`, I'll get `['a,b']` because it's just a name parameter with a comman (its value is "a,b")

Comment: I do not quite understand. If you want to get `['a,b']` then @deceze's solution is correct. `flask.request.getlist(<name>)` returns all parameters with the same name in a list. So you get a list containing a string. If you only pass one parameter you can also use `request.args.get(<name>)` and get `'a,b'` in your case. My solution splits this string based on the comma.

Comment: I want to get `['a', 'b']` for `/?name=a&name=b`
And `['a,b']` for `/?name=a,b`
The solution above gets me `['a','b']` in both